# Search array for email address and mask it

Tags: php

Having a little trouble here.

Below I have an example array that I am using.

```
$custom_replace = Array ( 
    [0] => 12345 
    [1] => (111) 111-1111 
    [2] => (111) 111-2222 
    [3] => email@address.com 
    [4] => 214113 
)
```

My goal is to be able to search this array for the email address and to mask it. What I have done so far is to:

```
    $dEmail = filter_var_array($custom_replace, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    $first = current(array_filter($dEmail));

    $newStr = $first; 

    $search = array("@", ".com", ".net", ".biz", ".me");  
    $replace = array(" at ", " dot com", " dot net", " dot biz", " dot me");  

    $mask = str_replace($search, $replace, $newStr);
    echo $mask;
```

The above code provides me with the ability to see the masked email. As for what the problem is? The "custom_replace" array is merged with another array as shown here:

```
$output = str_replace(array_merge($template_search, $custom_search), array_merge($template_replace, $custom_replace), html_entity_decode($settings["detail_format"], ENT_QUOTES));
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to take the masked value and include it in the array and to make it a part of the merge.

I look forward to your thoughts. I'll answer any questions to the best of my ability.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with just simple loops ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what you are trying to do exactly but based on the title of your question **"Search array for email address and mask it"**, you can try this out :

```
$regex_email = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/";
$array = array (12345, '(111) 111-1111', '(111) 111-2222', 'email@address.com', 214113);
$search = array("@", ".com", ".net", ".biz", ".me");  
$replace = array(" at ", " dot com", " dot net", " dot biz", " dot me");  

foreach($array as &$value){
    if ( preg_match( $regex_email, $value ) )
        $value = str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is not very clear on what you want, but I guess you are looking for a specific and accurate email address.

Here is the PHP code you should use in your case :

```
$custom_replace = array('12345', '(111) 111-1111' , '(111) 111-2222', 'email@address.com', '214113');
var_dump($custom_replace);

$email = 'email@address.com'; // Assuming, you are looking for a know string
$newArray = array();

foreach ($custom_replace as $value) {
  ($value == $email) ? '' : $newArray[] = $value;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Here is the result, and you will notice that there is no email address that you are trying to remove, and other data were reassembled into a new array.

Here are the results of the var_dump :

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> string(5) "12345"
  [1]=> string(14) "(111) 111-1111"
  [2]=> string(14) "(111) 111-2222"
  [3]=> string(17) "email@address.com"
  [4]=> string(6) "214113"
}

array(4) {
  [0]=> string(5) "12345"
  [1]=> string(14) "(111) 111-1111"
  [2]=> string(14) "(111) 111-2222"
  [3]=> string(6) "214113"
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/trN3Op)**